# Combobox how to get the selected item to show a theme

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm doing a tic tac toe game and I am trying to add a combo box that will  change the applications background based on what the person selects right now I have summer, spring, fall, winter and the images are in the bin/debug folder how can I get this to work I don't know where to start and the tutorials are a bit confusing. Could you please help me

Comment: Which parts do you need help with, exactly? Changing the images, handling the combobox SelectedIndexChanged event, or something else?

Comment: I can figure out the images what I need help with is the combo box i have in the combo box properties a collection "summer" "winter" how do i make it do something when selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't exactly clear what you are asking.  Assuming you've got bitmap files with names like "spring.png" etc in your bin\Debug folder, this ought to work:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        comboBox1.Items.AddRange(new string[] { "Spring", "Summer", "Fall", "Winter" });
        comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        string folder = Application.StartupPath;
        string theme = (string)comboBox1.Items[comboBox1.SelectedIndex];
        string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, theme + ".png");
        Image newImage = new Bitmap(path);
        if (this.BackgroundImage != null) this.BackgroundImage.Dispose();
        this.BackgroundImage = newImage;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.  This is probably the simplest:

1. Set your main form's `BackgroundImageLayout` to `Stretch`.
2. Place 4 `PictureBox` controls on your form, and set their `Visible` properties to `false`. Name them `pbWinter`, `pbSpring` etc. Set the `Image` property of each by browsing to the image file for each season.
3. Add a `ComboBox` to your form.  Add the items "Winter", "Spring", "Summer" and "Fall".
4. In the combo box's `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler, check the box's `Text` property with a `switch` statement, and set the appropriate back image with code like this:

   `this.BackgroundImage = pbWinter.Image; // etc. ...`

**Update:**  Here's how to do the switch statement:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (comboBox1.Text)
    {
        case "Winter":
            this.BackgroundImage = pbWinter.Image;
            break;
        case "Spring":
            this.BackgroundImage = pbSpring.Image;
            break;
        // etc...
    }
}
```